# PHP - MSSQL Connection without any Drivers

Tags: php, sql-server, odbc, sqlsrv

Can we connect to an MSSql database without ODBC or SQLSRV or other drivers? Is there any php library to make this connection?

Comment: "Can I drive my car without any wheels?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about PHP libraries but if you have SQL Server client installed then you can use `SQLCMD.EXE` utility to run a query against your MSSQL DB server.

Likewise in .NET I can invoke a external process (`SQLCMD` in this case) using `System.diagnostic.Process` class not sure if kind of same thing can be done in PHP. If it can then you probably don't need a specific driver.

Per your comment, at least ODBC driver must be present. Other than that just using a library it won't be possible cause any library behind the scene it has to use some driver through which it can pass the connection and connect to the server.

Comment: Nope, in MS website, it says "...sqlcmd uses the ODBC driver".

Comment: @rzon, that's bare minimum. Without any kind of driver it will not be possible to connect. See edit in answer.